# "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'playbutton' referenced before assignment" is happening when I remove my actor

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

When I replace my actor with the value "None" or anything else, it gives me this error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'playbutton' referenced before assignment

My code on the collide point is this:

```
    if playbutton.collidepoint(pos):
        playbuttonpressed = True
        print('Play button has been pressed')
        playbutton = None
        screen.fill((143, 188, 143))
        pygame.display.update()
        wait(1)
    else:
        print('Play button has not been pressed')
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is caused, because is `playbutton` is a variable in global namespace. If you delete `playbutton = None`, then `playbutton.collidepoint(pos)` use the variable in global namespace, because the variable is read (reading access) and you'll get no error.

As soon as you add the expression `playbutton = None`, `playbutton` is a variable in local scope of the function. `playbutton.collidepoint(pos)` wants to access the variable in local scope. Since the local variable is not assigned at the point you get the error

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'playbutton' referenced before assignment

Note, the compiler recognizes `playbutton` as a local variable, because of the assignment `playbutton = None` (before the code is actually executed), but the local variable `playbutton` is not assigned at `playbutton.collidepoint(pos)`.
See also [Why am I getting an UnboundLocalError when the variable has a value?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-am-i-getting-an-unboundlocalerror-when-the-variable-has-a-value)

---

Use the [`global` statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=global#grammar-token-global-stmt) to indicate that `playbutton` is meant to be a global variable when it is assigned and the global variable is changed instead of a local variable:

```
def your_function():
    # [...]

    global playbutton 

    if playbutton.collidepoint(pos):
        playbuttonpressed = True
        print('Play button has been pressed')
        playbutton = None
        # [...]
```

Comment: but I will try and fix it